# SparkSQL Dataframe access internal partitions (Columns)

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am working with some algorithms that require intensive computations over a dataset of numeric variables. I have really improved my pipeline by using **parquet** for storage and reading the data via the sparkSQL API, which allow me to read only the variables (columns) that are required for obtaining a given statistic.

However, once I obtain the corresponding **DataFrame**, I need to compute a single value by performing series of operations for each case in the data (rows) and then aggregating them. Neither the SQL operations or a UDF function are efficient for this, so I convert such Dataframe into an RDD and then apply a mapPartitions function to it.

```
df.rdd.mapPartitions( ... )
```

The resulting RDD is an RDD[Row] object, which is organised **row-wise**. So when triggering the map partitions, I have access to an iterator of Row objects, so I access my dataset case by case.

I wonder if there is an implicit way to access the data column by column, as the SparkSQL docs says that Dataframe structure is based on a **columnar storage**, so there must be a conversion when obtaining the RDD[Row] from it.

There must a way to access the internal partitions of a dataframe, in order to access the raw columns to operate with them as it will be much more natural for me to define my algorithm (like working with the columns of a matrix).

I dont know if this conversion is way deep into the implementation or can be accessed. I know that spark reads the parquet file (which is also column-wise organised) via the HDFS API, so I don't really know where the information is lost...

Any thoughts?